# Replace numerical values within a column in a sequential order based in condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to replace values in the col2 using this logic:

The original dataset has values starting to 1 to some value and return to 1, like that:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| data1 | 1 |
| data1 | 2 |
| data1 | 3 |
| data1 | 4 |
| data1 | 1 |
| data1 | 2 |
| data1 | 3 |
| data1 | 1 |
| data1 | 2 |
| data1 | 1 |
| data1 | 2 |
| data1 | 3 |

DESIRED:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| data1 | 1 |
| data1 | 1 |
| data1 | 1 |
| data1 | 1 |
| data1 | 2 |
| data1 | 2 |
| data1 | 2 |
| data1 | 3 |
| data1 | 3 |
| data1 | 4 |
| data1 | 4 |
| data1 | 4 |

I want to replace values using this logic:

When another number 1 pops up, I replace it with a sequential number 1, 2, 3, 4... until the end of the database. The col2 needs to be with that format, 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 ... the dataframe has plus 12000 rows.
Can someone help me with it please?

Comment: are you really looking to sort `col2`?

Comment: hi! Mark helped me solve it, but it was not to sort it, but replace the values according to the sequential until the end of the database. thanks btw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't want the numbers to start going down again, you can do this: check which rows equal 1, then get the cumulative sum of that series:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].eq(1).cumsum()

Output:
     col1  col2
0   data1     1
1   data1     1
2   data1     1
3   data1     1
4   data1     2
5   data1     2
6   data1     2
7   data1     3
8   data1     3
9   data1     4
10  data1     4
11  data1     4
```

Comment: if it doesn't match, a larger example would be great! :-)

Comment: it worked perfectly!! :) the cumulative sum did it to all sequences in the column. I was trying to do using if condition but I curled up haha thank a lot, Mark <3